# How to check if scroll position is at top or bottom in ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to implement a **infinite scroll** functionality.

I tried using a `ListView` inside on a `NotificationListener` to detect scroll events, but I can't see an event that says if the scroll has reached the bottom of the view.

Which would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use a `ListView.builder` to create a scrolling list with unlimited items. Your `itemBuilder` will be called as needed when new cells are revealed.

If you want to be notified about scroll events so you can load more data off the network, you can pass a `controller` argument and use `addListener` to attach a listener to the `ScrollController`. The `position` of the `ScrollController` can be used to determine whether the scrolling is close to the bottom.

Comment: Could you please explain us how to determine the maximum scroll offset of the ListView into the ScrollController ?

Comment: I just found the solution : scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent

Answer (score 170):

There are generally two ways of doing it.

**1. Using `ScrollController`**

```dart
// Create a variable
final _controller = ScrollController();
  
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  
  // Setup the listener.
  _controller.addListener(() {
    if (_controller.position.atEdge) {
      bool isTop = _controller.position.pixels == 0;
      if (isTop) {
        print('At the top');
      } else {
        print('At the bottom');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Usage:

```dart
ListView(controller: _controller) // Assign the controller.
```

---

**2. Using `NotificationListener`**

```dart
NotificationListener<ScrollEndNotification>(
  onNotification: (scrollEnd) {
    final metrics = scrollEnd.metrics;
    if (metrics.atEdge) {
      bool isTop = metrics.pixels == 0;
      if (isTop) {
        print('At the top');
      } else {
        print('At the bottom');
      }
    }
    return true;
  },
  child: ListView.builder(
    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
    itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text('Item $i')),
    itemCount: 20,
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thansk, you save my time

Comment: This answer should be higher. Tried the answers above but this answer is cleaner and easier to implement.

Comment: It detects the top of list but not the bottom.

Comment: NotificationListener works for me ;) thnx a lot

Comment: @CopsOnRoad,  How to resolve scroll-controller error when i want to use another listview.builder and track scroll inside first list view Item Builder ? i meant here : ListTile(title: Text('Item $i')) 

My target is to use nested /more inner list and track scroll top/bottom in inner to change physics and scroll immediate parent list view.

Comment: Like this improvement : https://github.com/nirav4273/flutter_nested_listview/issues ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69422101/flutter-nested-list-scroll-parent-child-scroll-control-is-not-working , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795503/flutter-nested-list-scroll-parent-when-reach-to-end-start-of-inner-list

Comment: It does not detect an end-scroll on a small number of items (where the listview is pulled but is not actually scrolled). Is there any solution to detect end-scroll on small lists?

Answer (score 41):

```
_scrollController = new ScrollController();

    _scrollController.addListener(
        () {
            double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
            double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
            double delta = 200.0; // or something else..
            if ( maxScroll - currentScroll <= delta) { // whatever you determine here
                //.. load more
            }
        }
    );
```

Collin's should be accepted answer....

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens is the answer to noam-aghai question ... this code creates a scrollController used to control the list and sticks a listener to let you know when is coming to its end and proceed to load more content or do whatever

Comment: on what basis we define value of "delta" ?

Comment: @AnujSharma there is no criteria.. its a random number for the sake of the example ... you can ignore it altogether and implement something different (like showing a loader at the end of the list) ....

Comment: make sure to limit your api call in this function because I will called as many time as possible if the you are at end of scroll and your first api call taking time to return data.

Comment: @NatwarSingh We can set a variable flag to know any api call is running now or not. If no api is running then can send api request on server or in vice-versa case system will not send any api request to server.

Answer (score 20):

I would like to add example for [answer provided by collin jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46379818/4764668). Refer following snippet

```
    var _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels == _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        // Perform your task
      }
    });
```

This will be only triggered when last item is visible in the list.

Answer (score 6):

A more simpler aproach is like this:

```
NotificationListener<ScrollEndNotification>(
    onNotification: onNotification,
    child: <a ListView or Wrap or whatever widget you need>
)
```

and create a method to detect the position:

```
 bool onNotification(ScrollEndNotification t) {
   if (t.metrics.pixels >0 && t.metrics.atEdge) {
     log('I am at the end');
   } else {
     log('I am at the start')
   }
   return true;
}
```

`t.metrics.pixel` is 0 when the  user is with the scrol at the top, as is more then 0 when the sure scrools. 
`t.metrics.atEdge` is `true` when the user is either at the top with the scrol **or** at the end with the scrol 
the `log` method is from package `import 'dart:developer';`

Answer (score 3):

I feel like this answer is a complement to Esteban's one (with extension methods and a throttle), but it's a valid answer too, so here it is:

Dart recently (not sure) got a nice feature, [method extensions](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods), which allow us to write the `onBottomReach` method like a part of the `ScrollController`:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension BottomReachExtension on ScrollController {
  void onBottomReach(VoidCallback callback,
      {double sensitivity = 200.0, Duration throttleDuration}) {
    final duration = throttleDuration ?? Duration(milliseconds: 200);
    Timer timer;

    addListener(() {
      if (timer != null) {
        return;
      }

      // I used the timer to destroy the timer
      timer = Timer(duration, () => timer = null);

      // see Esteban Díaz answer
      final maxScroll = position.maxScrollExtent;
      final currentScroll = position.pixels;
      if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= sensitivity) {
        callback();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here's a usage example:

```dart
// if you're declaring the extension in another file, don't forget to import it here.

class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  Screen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> {
  ScrollController_scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController()
      ..onBottomReach(() {
        // your code goes here
      }, sensitivity: 200.0, throttleDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Note: if you're using method extensions, you need to configure some things, see ["How to enable Dart Extension Methods"](https://quickbirdstudios.com/blog/dart-extension-methods/)

Answer (score 2):

```
  final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();


  void _listener() {

  double maxPosition = controller.position.maxScrollExtent;
  double currentPosition = controller.position.pixels;


  /// You can change this value . It's a default value for the 
  /// test if the difference between the great value and the current value is smaller 
  /// or equal
  double difference = 10.0;

  /// bottom position
  if ( maxPosition - currentPosition <= difference )
   
 
  /// top position
  else
   




if(mounted)
  setState(() {}); 
 }


@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  controller.addListener(_listener);
 }
```

Comment: please, provide some explenations if you want your code to be usefull

Answer (score 2):

You can use any one of below conditions :

```
 NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
    onNotification: (notification) {
      final metrices = notification.metrics;

      if (metrices.atEdge && metrices.pixels == 0) {
        //you are at top of  list

      }
      
      if (metrices.pixels == metrices.minScrollExtent) {
         //you are at top of list
      }

      if (metrices.atEdge && metrices.pixels > 0) {
        //you are at end of  list

      }

      if (metrices.pixels >= metrices.maxScrollExtent) {
        //you are at end of list
      }

      return false;
    },
     child: ListView.builder());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels >
          _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent + 5) {
        // do Something
      }
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        // do Something
      }
    });
  }
```

and add controller to your listview

```
ListView(controller: _scrollController, ...),
```

Answer (score 1):

I used different approach for infinite scrolling. I used [ChangeNotifie](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html)r class for variable change listener. 
If there is change in variable It triggers the event and eventually hit the API.

```
class DashboardAPINotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
   bool _isLoading = false;
    get getIsLoading => _isLoading;
    set setLoading(bool isLoading) => _isLoading = isLoading;
}
```

Initialize DashboardAPINotifier class.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _dashboardAPINotifier = DashboardAPINotifier();
    _hitDashboardAPI(); // init state

    _dashboardAPINotifier.addListener(() {
      if (_dashboardAPINotifier.getIsLoading) {
        print("loading is true");
        widget._page++; // For API page
        _hitDashboardAPI(); //Hit API
      } else {
        print("loading is false");
      }
    });

  }
```

Now the best part is when you have to hit the API. 
If you are using `SliverList`, Then at what point you have to hit the API.

```
SliverList(delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
       (BuildContext context, int index) {
        Widget listTile = Container();
         if (index == widget._propertyList.length - 1 &&
             widget._propertyList.length <widget._totalItemCount) {
             listTile = _reachedEnd();
            } else {
                    listTile = getItem(widget._propertyList[index]);
                   }
            return listTile;
        },
          childCount: (widget._propertyList != null)? widget._propertyList.length: 0,
    addRepaintBoundaries: true,
    addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
 ),
)


_reachEnd() method take care to hit the api. It trigger the `_dashboardAPINotifier._loading`

// Function that initiates a refresh and returns a CircularProgressIndicator - Call when list reaches its end
  Widget _reachedEnd() {
    if (widget._propertyList.length < widget._totalItemCount) {
      _dashboardAPINotifier.setLoading = true;
      _dashboardAPINotifier.notifyListeners();
      return const Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: const Center(
          child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      _dashboardAPINotifier.setLoading = false;
      _dashboardAPINotifier.notifyListeners();
      print("No more data found");
      Utils.getInstance().showSnackBar(_globalKey, "No more data found");
    }
  }
```

**Note:** After your API response you need to notify the listener,

```
setState(() {
        _dashboardAPINotifier.setLoading = false;
        _dashboardAPINotifier.notifyListeners();
        }
```

Comment: It's easier to use the ScrollController method and this adds a lot of messy code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package [scroll_edge_listener](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_edge_listener).

It comes with an offset and debounce time configuration which is quite useful. Wrap your scroll view with a `ScrollEdgeListener` and attach a listener. That's it.

```dart
ScrollEdgeListener(
  edge: ScrollEdge.end,
  edgeOffset: 400,
  continuous: false,
  debounce: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  dispatch: true,
  listener: () {
    debugPrint('listener called');
  },
  child: ListView(
    children: const [
      Placeholder(),
      Placeholder(),
      Placeholder(),
      Placeholder(),
    ],
  ),
),
```