# Flutter chat app, paginate the message stream

Tags: flutter

Ive got a simple chat feature in my app, only text.  Right now Im using a StreamProvider utilizing the Provider package. Like this:

```
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        FutureProvider.value(
            value: DatabaseProvider().getDMProfile(pairing.dmId)),
        FutureProvider.value(
            value: DatabaseProvider().getPlayerProfile(pairing.playerId)),
        StreamProvider.value(value: ChatProvider().streamMessages(chatName)),
      ],
      child: ChatScreen(
        hidden: isPlayer ? pairing.playerHidden : pairing.dmHidden,
        isPlayer: isPlayer,
        chatName: chatName,
      ),
    );
```

Heres the code for the stream:

```
Stream<List<Message>> streamMessages(String chatId) {
    var ref = db
        .collection(CHAT_COLLECTION)
        .document(chatId)
        .collection(MESSAGES_COLLECTION)
        .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true);
    return ref.snapshots().map((list) =>
        list.documents.map((doc) => Message.fromMap(doc.data)).toList());
  }
```

This all works fine as I create a ListView to display the chats.  What Im wondering is if pulling all the  messages like that is the right way to do it for efficiency.  And if not, how can I add in pagination so as the user scrolls up it loads additional past messages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes pulling all the messages like that can cost you a lot in the long run. You would need to look into pagination.

> With query cursors in Cloud Firestore, you can split data returned by a query into batches according to the parameters you define in your query.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

```
 var ref = db
    .collection(CHAT_COLLECTION)
    .document(chatId)
    .collection(MESSAGES_COLLECTION)
    .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).startAfter(<Date>).limit(<Number of documents you want to fetch>);
```

Once you understand this logic, you need to detect when to fetch additional data, as a tip, you can do this by detecting user's scroll.

More about it here:
[How to check if scroll position is at top or bottom in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377779/how-to-check-if-scroll-position-is-at-top-or-bottom-in-listview)

Once you understand both, you can come up with the pagination solution.