# Flutter - ScrollController with CupertinoSliverNavigationBar, largeTitle to smallTitle not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

When I use a ScrollController in a ListView, it blocks the CupertinoSliverNavigationBar largeTitle from transitioning to a smallTitle. However, if I remove the scrollController, the problem goes away. I think it might be a bug in the Cupertino Library

This code demonstrates the issue:

```
 ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
              largeTitle: Text('Large Title'),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: ListView.builder(
            controller: scrollController,
            itemCount: 50,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                height: 50,
                child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${index}')),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now if I remove the scrollController, the problem is gone:

```
ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
              largeTitle: Text('Large Title'),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: ListView.builder(
            //controller: scrollController,
            itemCount: 50,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                height: 50,
                child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${index}')),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an expected behavior since `NestedScrollView` is meant to manage the scroll positions of all other child scrolling views:

> #### NestedScrollView class
>
> A scrolling view inside of which can be nested other scrolling views,
> with their scroll positions being intrinsically linked.

So, you cannot control the positions of its children views with an individual `ScrollController`. However, you can provide one for `NestedScrollView` to manage all at once.

#### NotificationListener

There is still a way to listen to the scroll events of the inner scroll view besides using `ScrollController`. You can have your `ListView` inside of `NotificationListener` and check the scroll info that it provides.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return CupertinoPageScaffold(
    child: NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
            largeTitle: Text('Large Title'),
          ),
        ];
      },
      body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
          if (scrollInfo.metrics.pixels ==
              scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
            print('Reached the bottom');
          }
          return;
        },
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 50,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              height: 50,
              child: Center(child: Material(child: Text('Entry $index'))),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: The problem I have with placing the scrollController in the NestedScrollView (the parent) is that I cannot detect when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list. I can only accurately detect when the user scrolls to the bottom if the controller is placed in the child listView. None of the solutions mentioned here work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377779/how-to-check-if-scroll-position-is-at-top-or-bottom-in-listview

Comment: Now, I understood your situation better and added an example which demonstrates what you want to do.