# How to show image in vertical PageView?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, pageviews

I want to make a vertical image viewer.

But when the Image is bigger than the screen, top&bottom of the image are hidden.

[image]

So I made Pageview and put ListView in PageView.

Now I can scroll down until the end of the ListView but can't scroll PageView.

I want to make 'complete' scrollview in the flutter.

How can I make scroll view in flutter?

```
PageView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    pageSnapping: false,
                    onPageChanged: (index) {
                      setState(() {
                        _currentSlider = index;
                      });
                    },
                    children: file.getImages
                        .map((e) => Center(
                              child: ListView(
                                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                children: [
                                  Image.memory(
                                    e,
                                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                  )
```

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: @JediBurrell Ok. I updated code.

Comment: @pskink Yes. I already tried that solution. But I can't scroll PageView in SingleChildScrollView. I want to scroll PageView in smooth.

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't work in landscape mode. I just want vertical scroll view. like this. [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MrBendel/APLoopingScrollView/master/APLoopingScrollView/APLoopingScrollView/gifs/vert.gif)

Comment: No, It doesn't work. I am trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67515358/how-to-put-listview-inside-pageview-and-scroll-both-of-them-vertically/67515359?noredirect=1#comment119685956_67515359) now.

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work neither.

Comment: Yes. That's what I tried. Now I use photo_view and It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a SingleChildScrollView() like so:

```
PageView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      pageSnapping: false,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        setState(() {
          _currentSlider = index;
        });
      },
      children: file.getImages
          .map((e) => Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListView(
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                children: [
                  Image.memory(
                    e,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
      ))
          .toList(),
    )
```

Comment: It doesn't work without 'shrinkWrap: true'. With 'shrinkWrap: true', it works same as my example.