# Switch horizontal tabs on vertical scroll flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, scrollview

How can I switch tabs on a vertical scroll as shown above. What would be the best way to do this? And upon clicking on certain tab, control should be transfer to selected tab content. I tried to find solution on google but in vain.

Currently my code looks something like this but I know thats not it.

```
class SingleRestView extends StatefulWidget {
  Restaurant singleRestaurant;
  SingleRestView({@required this.singleRestaurant});
  @override
  _SingleRestViewState createState() => _SingleRestViewState();
}

class _SingleRestViewState extends State<SingleRestView>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  var _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var tabBar = TabBar(
      controller: _tabController,
      //This property will allow your tabs to be horizontally scrollable
      isScrollable: true,
      indicatorColor: Colors.black,
      labelColor: Colors.black,
      tabs: [
       Text("Tab 1"),
       Text("Tab 2"),
       Text("Tab 2"),
      ],
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, isScrolled) => [
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 300,
            pinned: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text('Title'),
              //Without this padding the title appears behind the tabs.
              //This is the whole reason why the tabBar is in a local variable, to
              //be able to use its height here.
              titlePadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                  start: 72, bottom: tabBar.preferredSize.height + 16),
              // background:
            ),
            // I did this this way to have a white bottom bar like in your photo,
            // however, you could just pass the tabBar. The background image would
            //be behind it.
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              child: Container(
                //This will keep your tabs centered if you have not enough to fill
                //the display's width
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: tabBar,
              ),
              preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, tabBar.preferredSize.height),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: <Widget>[
           Container(height: 50,width: 100,color: Colors.red,),
           Container(height: 50,width: 100,color: Colors.blue,),
           Container(height: 50,width: 100,color: Colors.green,),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Video of what i want to achieve](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/BogusPoliticalDwarfrabbit-mobile.mp4)

Comment: Hi Faizan , I have listed out some of the possible options & also attached some further references for reading, I would suggest that you should definitely check them out. Thanks for your question :)

Answer (score 1):

`nestedScrollController` has a property called `offset` which will give you the current offset.

```
nestedScrollController.offset
```

But remember, screen sizes can be different for different devices. So using only offset will *not* help.

---

**1. Naive Option using MediaQuery**

With `MediaQuery` you can get to know the height of your device & then you can globally change the `tab_index` based on a comparison between offset & the height of the device. You can use some **threshold value** after which horizontal `tab_index` changes. Setting proper offset values might be a tough job !

```
double new_height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

if(new_height/2<=offset)
{
//change my tab_index to 2
}
```

**2. Using Listeners in Controller**

Combining listeners & offsets

```
 _TabController.addListener(() {
    if (_controller.position.atEdge) {
      if (_controller.position.pixels == 0) {
        // You're at the top so tab_index=1 
      }

      //At the bottom of screen

      if(_controller.offset>=_controller.position.maxScrollExtent)
      {
         //set your tab_index
      }

      //middle of screen multiply by 0.5
      
      if(_controller.offset>=_controller.position.maxScrollExtent*0.5)
      {
         //set your tab_index
      } 
      
     //3/4 of screen multiply by 0.75
     
     if(_controller.offset>=_controller.position.maxScrollExtent*0.75)
      {
         //set your tab_index
      } 

    }
```

**Further Reading -**

1. https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac
2. [Scroll Position Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPosition-class.html)
3. [How to check if scroll position is at top or bottom in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377779/how-to-check-if-scroll-position-is-at-top-or-bottom-in-listview)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to use this plugin => https://pub.dev/packages/vertical_scrollable_tabview/score

```dart
import 'package:vertical_scrollable_tabview/vertical_scrollable_tabview.dart';

// Required it
TabBar(
    onTap: (index) {
        VerticalScrollableTabBarStatus.setIndex(index); <- Required 
    },
)

and

VerticalScrollableTabView(
    tabController: tabController,                             <- Required TabBarController
    listItemData: data,                                       <- Required List<dynamic>
    eachItemChild: (object,index){
        return CategorySection(category: object as Category); <- Object and index
    },
    verticalScrollPosition: VerticalScrollPosition.begin,
),
```

I think this plugin can solve it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The problem with this is that i can't move directly to the tab bar content upon clicking the single tab. Below is what I'm trying to say
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IrhQ37145ipjdzVMWaiMFmr3dhqFSrQT/view?usp=sharing