# Is there any way to perform some action when list item fully swiped to the end. (action except removing item) (library :- flutter_slidable )

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I want this type of behavior in list view item swipe.

1. When user swipe half the list item I want to show some options.
2. When user click on that option I am performing some task.
3. **When a user swipes an item all the way through to end(mean full swipe), I don't want to remove it; instead, I want to perform a task, and when that task or process is finished, I want to dismiss the swipe.**

Here is my Code!

```
child: SlidableAutoCloseBehavior(

              child: ListView.separated(
                itemBuilder: ((context, index) => Slidable(
                    closeOnScroll: true,
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    startActionPane: ActionPane(
                      dismissible: DismissiblePane(
                        onDismissed: () {
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                              msg: "Full swipe ${index + 1}");
                       
                        },
                      ),
                      motion: BehindMotion(),
                      children: [
                        SlidableAction(
                            onPressed: (BuildContext context) {
                              Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                  msg: "Unlock ${index + 1}");
                            },
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            label: "Unlock",
                            icon: Icons.lock_open),
                        SlidableAction(
                            onPressed: (BuildContext context) {
                              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Lock ${index + 1}");
                            },
                            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                            label: "Lock",
                            icon: Icons.lock_outline),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: listViewItem(index))),
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    const Divider(),
                itemCount: list.length,
              ),
            )
```

I had accomplished the first and second points successfully, but I have no idea how to archive the third point.

Comment: Would this help: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable

Comment: I did utilize that package here. Check the code, please.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize as there are no import statement. Let me look again.

Comment: oky let me add that! so other can recognize it.

Comment: I suggest you look at what the scroll controller property of listview can do for you. Also this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377779/how-to-check-if-scroll-position-is-at-top-or-bottom-in-listview

Comment: I am taking about swipe .. not scrolling... When user swipe the item fully to from left tk right I want to perform task but here it removes item from list. If you want I'll edit the question with video so you can understand.